# Why is ubuntu setting file type to hfs+

Tags: filesystem, external-hdd, read-only, hfs+

I recently installed Ubuntu desktop onto a raspberry pi for and for some reason it is registering my external hard drive as HFS plus even though I've never used a Mac computer before in my life. Now I can't copy files to the hard drive or do anything with the hard drive besides view. The files already on the hard drive were put there by a Windows computer so I don't see why it's using an apple formatting system. Even though I'm logged in as root it just says the file system is read only and won't let me edit anything. Changing the permissions won't do anything as the file system is listed as read-only is there any way I can change this without losing all of my files as there's over a terabyte of data there?